# Which type of collections to use for storing a country list

Tags: java, list, hashmap

Hi I'm trying to store a country list where I've wrote down all countries in a text file. Im trying to put the list in a HashMap in java but no success so far.
I want to sort the keys by first letter eg.(Key="A" gives Value(Algeria)) and i also want to have multiple values for each key to hold.
Is there any other way to accomplish this?

```java
//containers for the country names
private Map<String, List<String>> letter_map;
private List<List<String>> letter_list;
private String[] letters = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "E", "F", "G", "I", "J", "K", 
                            "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};//0-25



public void country_handler(){
    String tempLetter;
    int i = 0;
    letter_list = new ArrayList<List<String>>(25);
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //file path
    File f = new File("/Users/rojandinc/Documents/workspace/First_letter_game/src/game_logic/countries");

    //read file into list
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {//file reader
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && i < 26) {//read in every line (country)
           if(line.startsWith(letters[i].toString())){
               tempList.add(line);
           }
           else{
               letter_list.add(tempList);
               tempList.clear();
               tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
               tempList.add(line);
               i++;
           }           
        }

        //add values to map
        for(int j = 0; j < letter_list.size(); j++){
            letter_map.put(letters[j].toString(), letter_list.get(j));
        }

    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Done with map");
}
```

Comment: What is your question/problem? Does your code work? Are you getting errors? Why do you need another way to accomplish it?

Comment: @tcooc I get a nullpointerexception and every list is getting replaced with the same values. I would just like to get help with the easiest way to accomplish my goal.